# How to compose a Single<T> with multiple futures

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Assume I have below code:

```
    public Single<C> gen(String input1, String input2) {

    //TODO
    }

    private Future<A> remote1(final String input1) {

    }

    private Future<B> remote2(final String input2) {

    }
```

and I can use A + B to create C, like new C(A a, B b).

How am I supposed to write the code with remote1 and remote2 run in parallel.

I'm not sure whether my way is correct or efficient:

```
    Flowable<A> f1 = Flowable.fromFuture(remote1(input1));
    Flowable<B> f2 = Flowable.fromFuture(remote2(input2));

    Single<C> result = Flowable.combineLatest(f1, f2, new BiFunction<A, B, C>(){

        @Override
        public C apply(A a, B b) throws Exception {
            return new C(a, b);
        }}).firstOrError();
```

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Single<A> f1 = Single.fromFuture(remote1(input1));
Single<B> f2 = Single.fromFuture(remote2(input2));

Single<C> result = Single.zip(f1, f2, new BiFunction<A, B, C>(){

    @Override
    public C apply(A a, B b) throws Exception {
        return new C(a, b);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, much better than mine! Thanks a lot!!